# there is something wrong with sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

following sql query was working fine, i don't whats wrong i did its stopped fetching records.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_table  where pid=$saa1 OR gpid=$saa1 OR     
category_id=$saa1 ORDER BY autoid desc limit $no2,20")
or die(mysql_error());
```

when i remove or clause its works fine for example

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_table ORDER BY autoid desc limit 
$no2,20")
or die(mysql_error());
```

please have a look and let me know where i am doing mistake....

regards,

Comment: I doubt the second works.

Comment: o sorry where should not be here...

Comment: what actually get when executing the above queries in mysql

Comment: what is the value of `$saa1`? And did you pay attention to SQL Injection?? (i.e. validated your variables before throwing them into your query)

Comment: What does the query look like after php runs through it, echo out the query:

echo "SELECT * FROM product_table  where pid=$saa1 OR gpid=$saa1 OR     
category_id=$saa1 ORDER BY autoid desc limit $no2,20";

Comment: SELECT * FROM product_table where pid=643 OR gpid=643 OR category_id=643 ORDER BY autoid desc limit 0,200

Comment: well put that thru and see if you actually have data that matches

Comment: Not likely that the query just magically broke. Much more likely that the data passed is invalid, or there are no results... anyhow, do you actually get a mysql_error?

Comment: of course the data changed !

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems,your query is OK, but when you use `WHERE` clause, you limit the results , so perhaps there is no recored for display, especially when you use `LIMIT` for starting offset and number of results.

Comment: it is not especially because of limit 0,200. it is because there is nothing for id 643

Comment: I did not know about LIMIT 0,200. if yes, then your mention is true. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query is ok but there is no record to satisfy your `where` part. go to your database and create some new rows with your criteria.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_table  where (pid=$saa1 OR gpid=$saa1 OR     
category_id=$saa1) ORDER BY autoid desc limit $no2,20")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: syntactically this isolates the OR statements within the WHERE clause.  I would use something like this in SQL Server.  I would think it's the same here.  Did you try the query? Did this work for you?

Comment: what you are doing is for your visual benefit as it does nothing to change the results of what he wrote. it is like wrapping the on clause like "(one t2.id=t1.id)". it does not help the dbengine, it helps the programmer with his style. his problem is that there was no match, and in realizing that he did as many do with silly questions ... they don't come back and fess up. btw i did not downvote you i do not do that :> so maybe i will upvote u !